# Clean HTML table of formatting?

Tags: html, html-table

Anyone know of a way to clean a `<table>` of all formatting leaving just the basic tags and text?

I have tries Komposer which was useless and even added more formatting rubbish of its own.  I them tried Aptana but that only seems to be a text editor, again no use at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you clarify? Do you want to remove the borders?

Comment: Why is a text editor no use? If you want full control of your HTML, you really need to write it by hand.

Comment: Can you post an example of the HTML you're trying to "clean"?
Do you want to remove references to CSS classes, or inline styles (or both?)?
Is this a one-off task or do you need to run it in an automated fashion multiple times?

Comment: This is a large table which I am trying to clean as a one off.  It has lots of style=, class=, height=, width= attributes and also some font tags.  I want to remove all of this so I am left with just basic table, tr, td tags and the actual text.

Comment: You could remove attributes like style class etc with a regular expression. Unfortunately, that's not really my business...

Answer (score 2):

When you would like to clean HTML tables (e.g. when you copy them from Word or Excel to an HTML editor) you can use the online Table Cleaner at https://www.r2h.nl/tablecleaner

I strips all the formatiing and returns only clean HTML code so will you have a table without any styling.

Comment: This tool is very useful. codebeautify.org and jsfiddle.net also has some tidying features.  Also, htmltidy.org does similiar but to all HTML.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a text editor that supports find and replace using regular expressions (such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) to remove the unwanted attributes using one regex, and the `font` tags using another regex?

To match the attributes you need to remove the following regex should do the job:

`( style| class| height| width)=("[A-Za-z0-9:;_ -]*"|'[A-Za-z0-9:;_ -]*'|[A-Za-z0-9:;_-]*)`

To match font tags, try

`<font.*font>`

(I've tested these regular expressions with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

### Edit

It turns out that Notepad++ does not support the logical OR operator in regular expressions. An alternative would be to use another text editor that *does*, or to write a small app/script to perform the replacements.

Comment: Would possibly get rid of some of the problem attributes but would still leave the font tags & end font tags in place.  Actualy just tried that in notepad++ but the regular expression doesn't seem to work, doesn't seem to like the 'or' separator.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example regex for `font` tags.